# How to set width of container with two div's

Tags: html, css

I want make a "container" for two div's, but i don't know how to set width of it.

HTML Code:

```
<div id="controller"><!-- i use it to center div's -->
    <!-- i think set start of container here (id="container") -->
        <div id="first">Some Content</div>
        <div id="second">Some Content</div>
    <!-- and end here -->
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
#controller {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#first {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 360px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: green;
}

#second {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 880px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: your question is vague, please be a little more specific. what are you trying to accomplish with setting a width? what should the container look like?

Comment: this controller to set divs at center

Comment: Close it, i found answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If your problem is that the wrapping div utilizes the whole width available and you only want it to wrap around the two inner div's:*

It does that because the default value of a div is display: block.

For it to only take the width of the two inner div's you can **set it to display: inline-block**, there are a dozen ways to do this though.

Example:

```
#controller {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: yellow;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Or watch this codepen I created for this example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWxpgP

Answer (score 0):

Set `margin:auto;` for `#controller` , check below codes

```css
#controller {
    height: auto;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#first {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: green;
}

#second {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 200px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="controller"><!-- i use it to center div's -->
    <!-- i think set start of container here (id="container") -->
        <div id="first">Some Content</div>
        <div id="second">Some Content</div>
    <!-- and end here -->
</div>
```